# Reason for including scorecardresearch.com

Tags: discussion, architecture

What is the reason for SO/SE to include data from http://www.scorecardresearch.com and http://www.quantserve.com? Are there any downsides for me or SO/SE having NoScript and uBlock blocking them? The sites work fine, but I wonder if I am missing something or if this information would be crucial for SO/SE to better operate; in which case I would definitely allow them. One that is only sometimes used is http://adzerk.net/. I know what they to, but wonder how important they are for the whole ecosystem.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263619/are-some-se-web-tracking-beacons-more-important-than-others/263625#263625

Comment: Brilliant, thank you @Oded. This was exactly what I was looking for. I'll enable those three then, so as to support and give back some value of the countless hours I have saved finding some true gems on this ecosystem.